# How to detect a signed pdf is valid with iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

For a project, I need to check if a digital signature is valid or not.
I already developed a piece of code to do it.
I tested with some pdf (correct or not) and the code seems to work.
But there is a case where the verification does not work.

In Adobe Reader I've the message "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed." with a "beautiful" red cross...
Unfortunately, I don't know how to test this case which is the most important.

Because if I understand, the signature is correct, but it's the document which is altered, not the signature.

I suppose we can use the hash of file, but I don't know how to extract correctly this information.

**How to check that with Itext ?**

For information, I tested the methods as below :

- *pdfpkcs7.verify()*: return true
- *acroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(signame)*: return true
- *pdfReader.isRebuilt()* : return false

Comment: Please share the pdf in question. Considering the test method results you post I would *assume* that the pdf in question has its **NeedAppearances** flag set. This causes Adobe Reader to (re)create form field appearances when it opens the file which changes the signed data. Another option might be a pdf with a signature which uses a signing algorithm not supported by Adobe.

Comment: Thanks for help, the link of document : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8fLGZLVFcLyeXF0TjluNzRjT3c/view?usp=sharing

The error is occured during tests there is some time and I forgot how I generated it ....

Comment: I'm actually not sure yet. Currently I favor the assumption that Adobe Reader simply does not support the combination of algorithms used in your document. Adobe Reader supports only a very limited set of algorithms, cf. [Acrobat_DigSig_AlgorithmsAll](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/QuickKeys/Acrobat_DigSig_AlgorithmsAll.pdf) which continuously states that *"DSA only supports SHA1"*. Your PDF, on the other hand, uses DSA in combination with SHA-256. BouncyCastle, the security library used by iText, supports a far more extensive set of algorithms and algorithm combinations.

Comment: Thank you ! I confirm that with SHA-1 there is no error

Comment: Ok, I'll tentatively make that an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe has documented their selection of algorithms accepted in signatures in [this document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/QuickKeys/Acrobat_DigSig_AlgorithmsAll.pdf). In particular they therein state for all applicable PDF versions

> DSA only supports SHA1 and adbe.pkcs7.detached

The OP's document, on the other hand, uses DSA with SHA256. The effect is that

- Adobe Reader cannot positively validate the hash value but
- iText (not restricting itself to those algorithm combinations) can.

---

Actually the signing algorithm information in signature itself is questionable to start with, it merely uses the OID 1.2.840.10040.4.1 which only indicates that DSA is used, not the digest algorithm it is used with. Strictly speaking a different OID should have been used:

- for SHA1withDSA: 1.2.840.10040.4.3
- for SHA256withDSA: 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2

(There even are some alternatives most of which meanwhile have been deprecated.)

Finding only 1.2.840.10040.4.1 (only DSA) validators have to guess / deduce the digest, and assuming SHA1 (like Adobe Reader does) is not completely unreasonable.

iText most likely guesses the used SHA256 because this digest algorithm is also used to calculate the document digest in the signed attribute `messageDigest`.

Answer (score 0):

iText :Avoiding the PDF Digital Signature Vulnerabilities with iText. [links](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/avoiding-pdf-digital-signature-vulnerabilities-itext)

> In February 2019, a team of security researchers from the Ruhr-University Bochum in Germany published details of vulnerabilities in the digital signing system of many PDF viewers and online PDF digital signing services. After investigating these vulnerabilities, we found that recent updates to iText introduced in version 7.1.5 mean we are not vulnerable to the described attacks.

> However, it was determined that the current names of the methods for checking and verifying signatures could be improved to better reflect their functionality. Therefore we have decided to deprecate the SignatureUtil#verifySignature and PdfPKCS7#verify methods, and replace them with SignatureUtil#readSignatureData  and PdfPKCS7#verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity which have been introduced in iText 7.1.6.

Below are code examples showing how to use the signature integrity and authenticity checks for each of these versions of iText.
iText 7.1.6:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input));
 
// Checks that signature is genuine and the document was not modified.
boolean genuineAndWasNotModified = false;
 
String signatureFieldName = "Signature1";
SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
try {
    PdfPKCS7 signature1 = signatureUtil.readSignatureData(signatureFieldName);
    if (signature1 != null) {
        genuineAndWasNotModified = signature1.verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity();
    }
} catch (Exception ignored) {
    // ignoring exceptions,
    // we are only interested in signatures that are passing the check successfully
}
 
pdfDocument.close();
```

> The second and third types of attack, Incremental Saving Attack (ISA) and Signature Wrapping (SWA), are based on attempts to insert into the PDF file some malicious data to override signed data.

> In order to validate every signature, it is necessary to check if it covers the entire file, otherwise iText cannot be sure that signature in question indeed signs the data that constitutes the current PdfDocument and all its contents. Even though the signature is authentic and signed data integrity is intact, iText will always check that signed data is not only a part of the PDF content but is also a valid PDF file.

> iText implements this check in the SignatureUtil.signatureCoversWholeDocument(String fieldName) method. For both ISA and SWA attacks, this method will return false, because some unsigned data was inserted into the file:

> We actually addressed this specific issue back in November 2018 (before we were aware of the reported vulnerabilities) with a rewrite of the signatureCoversWholeDocument() method. Providing you use iText 7.1.5 (or newer) the following code should correctly validate the PDF:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input));
 
String signatureFieldName = "Signature1";
SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
 
Boolean completeDocumentIsSigned = signatureUtil.signatureCoversWholeDocument(signatureFieldName)}
if (!completeDocumentIsSigned) 
{
    // handle PDF file which contains NOT signed data
}
 
pdfDocument.close();
```

Note: Signatures that do not cover the entire document cannot be considered as verifying the PDF file, because content that is not covered by the signature might have been modified since the signature was created.